# Make content of header disappear when menu opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I basically want to make that when I press on a button the first time it adds display: none; to an element and when I press it again it makes the element appear again (so add display: none;). How would I do this with jQuery?

This is the jQuery I tried to implement but as I'm new to Javascript I don't know why it isn't working.

```js
$('#menuBtn').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
    $('.header-text').css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
  } else {
    $('.header-text').css({
      'display': 'block'
    });
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] ? HTML is also very important here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [toggle](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) or [slideToggle (With animation)](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

```js
$('#menuBtn').on('click', function() {
    $('.header-text').toggle();
});
$('#menuBtnSlide').on('click', function() {
    $('.header-text').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="menuBtn">Toggle</button>
<button id="menuBtnSlide">SlideToggle</button>

<div class="header-text">
This content must me show and hide
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could supply a modifier class in some external stylesheet for hiding the text and toggle it via [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

**Word of advice:** It's best not to use something like [toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) because it will inject inline css into your elements, making it difficult to override in the long-run for something so simplistic.

```js
const $headerText = $('.header-text');

$('#menuBtn').click(function() {
  $headerText.toggleClass('header-text--hidden');
});
```

```css
.header-text--hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="menuBtn" type="button">Toggle</button>

<header>
  <p class="header-text">Text 1</p>
  <p class="header-text">Text 2</p>
  <p class="header-text">Text 3</p>
  <p class="header-text">Text 4</p>
</header>
```

Comment: There is a much simpler solution with jQuery, this code adds complexity

Comment: What's complex about declaring a variable and checking it's state on click?

Comment: In itself it is not complex, but for this use it is. jQuery has a function for this purpose, why not use it?

Comment: One main reason is because a jQuery method like this one injects inline styles to your elements, which make it a headache to override if external CSS is also used. If you're gonna do anything involving style changes, it's best to apply them separately as I'll demonstrate in my updated code.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need jQuery for this.

You can add CSS rule to set `.hidden` to `display: none` and then [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) that class when the button is clicked.

To catch the click event on the button, you need a [click event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
const header = document.querySelector('.header');
const toggle = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');

toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  header.classList.toggle('hidden')
});
```

```css
.header {
  background: red;
  height: 3em;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="header"></header>
<button class="menu-toggle">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.hidden{display:none !important;}`

```
$('#menuBtn').click(function() {
    $('.header-text').toggleClass("hidden");        
});
```